# Set html Select option using c#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Okay, so this seems like an easy thing to do but I cannot find how to do it. I have used the `htmlagility` pack to parse the web page and it works great. Now, the issue is that the following.

```
<td width="45%" class="TextBold" nowrap>
<select name="ctl00$BodyContent$ddlChooseView" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex > 0
{pageTracker._trackEvent('webpage tracker','complete report',this.options
[this.selectedIndex].text);}
ShowProcessing(this);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$BodyContent$ddlChooseView\',\'\')', 
    0)" id="ctl00_BodyContent_ddlChooseView" class="TextBold">
        <option selected="selected" value=""> -- Select a view -- </option>
        <option value="H">Option1</option>
        <option value="R">Option2</option>
        <option value="N">Option3</option>
        <option value="NA">Option4</option>
        <option value="RN">Option5</option>
        <option value="QP">Option6</option>

</select>
</td>
```

I apologize if this did not format correctly. And I want to select one of the options in the `html` select object. To trigger a new display on the page and then parse that "new" webpage. Can `htmlagilitypack` do this? If not, what can I do to select one of the options?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused with what `HtmlAgilityPack` can do...

`HtmlAgilityPack` - is just a praser.

From `browser's point of view`, selecting one of the option will lead browser to send a `POST` type request to the page.

What you can do now is, simulate that `POST` request either with `WebClient` or with `HttpWebRequest`, then you will get your `new web page` you can work on that new WebPage using `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Comment: The issue is that it is not a new webpage, it merely loads a table with the information I want to parse.

Comment: @Fatstink - check one more of the answer given! i have read few places `Selenium WebDriver` is capable of doing that!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily by using selenium webdriver.
Read about it, good for handling this kind of stuff.

Here i first select the element that got the option using Webdriver library

     `var selectElem = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_BodyContent_ddlChooseView"));`

Now using WebDriver.Support.UI library i get all the options

    `SelectElement selectOption = new SelectElement(selectElem);`

Now u can perform any action on the element. ie

 like 
    `selectOption.SelectByValue("here u give the value")` 

or 

`selectOption.SelectByText("here u give the value")`

and many more... that you discover out.

Comment: So if I am looking to use this on many computers I would have to distribute Selenium to each user as well?

Comment: Okay, I like this option, I am having issues with SelectOption showing up, I have linked the Support UI library but Intellisense cannot find SelectOption?

Comment: You need to use webdriver library to be able to work with it, and add reference to your project. You can easily download it from their website.

Answer (score 0):

This code may be useful to you It contains the basic details.

```
<code>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

//Need to add these two libarary
//For that u need to have WebDriver.dll and WebDriver.Support.dll 
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace Test
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
//Intializing the webdriver. 
//Note i m using firefox driver, others can also be used.
IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();
//Navigating to the given page.
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url of the page you want to get the option from");
//Finding the element. If element not present it throws exception so do remember to handle it.
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_BodyContent_ddlChooseView"));
//No intializing the select element option.
SelectElement selectElem = new SelectElement(element);
selectElem.SelectByValue("H"); 
//or i can select option using text that is
selectElem.SelectByText("Option1"); 
}

}
}
</code>
```

Sorry for the indentation.

Comment: I appreciate it, is there way to set this so that it does not actually open a browser, I would like to merely select the drop down item so that I can parse the page again. I need this to not open anything else.